# JOIN of 2 tables where cross all records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, relational-division

Given these 2 tables

Table name: MyValues

| Id | IdValue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 1 | 11 |

Table name: MyConditions

| Id | IdValue |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 10 |
| 7 | 11 |

How could I write a query to get the Ids from the MyValues table to return the ones that match all the records on MyConditions table where MyValues.IdValue = MyConditions.IdValue

So the result would be 1 (since Id 1 from MyValues table matches all records in MyConditions table)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: What happens if there is another row in `MyValues: 1, 12`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reads like a relational division problem. We can join, and filter with `having`:

```
select v.id
from myvalues v
inner join myconditions c on c.idvalue = v.idvalue
group by v.id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from myconditions)
```

This assumes no duplicate `(id, idvalue)` in `myvalue`, and no duplicate `idvalue` in `mycondition`. Otherwise, we would typically use `distinct` on one or both side of `having`:

```
having count(distinct v.idvalue) = (select count(distinct idvalue) from myconditions)
```